# Group XML Elements based on element values and attributes using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to iterate through XML elemets grouping the data by a common element value.
The input XML structure is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
<output outputType="CORRECTION">
    <row nodeName="ORDER_HEADER" tableName="ORDER_HEADER">
        <column columnName="ORDER_NUMBER">00001</column>
        <column columnName="Country">England</column>
        <column columnName="City">London</column>
    </row>
    <row nodeName="ORDER_HEADER" tableName="ORDER_HEADER">
        <column columnName="ORDER_NUMBER">00002</column>
        <column columnName="Country">England</column>
        <column columnName="City">Birmingham</column>
    </row>
    <row nodeName="ORDER_DETAIL" tableName="ORDER_DETAIL">
        <column columnName="ORDER_NUMBER">00001</column>
        <column columnName="Book">Gone with the wind</column>
        <column columnName="Qty">2</column>
    </row>
    <row nodeName="ORDER_DETAIL" tableName="ORDER_DETAIL">
        <column columnName="ORDER_NUMBER">00001</column>
        <column columnName="Book">Pride and Prejudice</column>
        <column columnName="Qty">3</column>
    </row>
    <row nodeName="ORDER_DETAIL" tableName="ORDER_DETAIL">
        <column columnName="ORDER_NUMBER">00002</column>
        <column columnName="Book">Jane Eyre</column>
        <column columnName="Qty">1</column>
    </row>
</output>
</Data>
```

I am trying to create the following output:

```
<Transmission xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <OrderNumber>00001</OrderNumber>
    <Country>England</Country>
    <City>London</CITY>
    <Book>Gone with the wind</Book>
    <QTY>2</QTY>
    <Book>Pride and Prejudice</Book>
    <QTY>3</QTY>
    <OrderNumber>00002</OrderNumber>
    <Country>England</Country>
    <City>Birmingham</CITY>
    <Book>Jane Eyre</Book>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
</Transmission>
```

Here is the XSL I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/Data/output[@outputType='CORRECTION']">
    <Transmission>
        <xsl:for-each select="row[@tableName='ORDER_HEADER']">
            <OrderNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='ORDER_NUMBER']" />
            </OrderNumber>
            <Country>
                <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='Country']" />
            </Country>
            <City>
                <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='City']" />
            </City>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Transmission>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can output the details from each order header but can't see how to select and group the correct order details.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a key to look up the order details (which works in both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0)

```
<xsl:key name="detail" match="row[@nodeName='ORDER_DETAIL']" use="column[@columnName='ORDER_NUMBER']" />
```

Then, to get the order details for a given order number, you can use the key like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('detail', column[@columnName='ORDER_NUMBER'])">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="detail" match="row[@nodeName='ORDER_DETAIL']" use="column[@columnName='ORDER_NUMBER']" />
<xsl:template match="/Data/output[@outputType='CORRECTION']">
    <Transmission>
        <xsl:for-each select="row[@tableName='ORDER_HEADER']">
            <xsl:variable name="orderNumber" select="column[@columnName='ORDER_NUMBER']" />
            <OrderNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="$orderNumber" />
            </OrderNumber>
            <Country>
                <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='Country']" />
            </Country>
            <City>
                <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='City']" />
            </City>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('detail', $orderNumber)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Transmission>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <Book>
        <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='Book']" />
    </Book>
    <QTY>
        <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='Qty']" />
    </QTY>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, I switched to use `xsl:apply-templates` instead, just to cut-down on too much nested code. I also used a variable, to avoid some repetition of getting the order number.

As an aside, is that really the XML output you want? It would probably be more logical to wrap each order in a containing parent element like so, otherwise extracting the books for an order becomes a bit more hard work.

```
<Transmission>
 <Order>
   <OrderNumber>00001</OrderNumber>
   <Country>England</Country>
   <City>London</City>
   <Book>Gone with the wind</Book>
   <QTY>2</QTY>
   <Book>Pride and Prejudice</Book>
   <QTY>3</QTY>
 </Order>
 <Order>
   <OrderNumber>00002</OrderNumber>
   <Country>England</Country>
   <City>Birmingham</City>
   <Book>Jane Eyre</Book>
   <QTY>1</QTY>
 </Order>
</Transmission>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much for a clear and concise solution.  This has helped enormously.